# ngx-datatable: pageSize vs limit

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

Trying to integrate ng-datatable into my Angular 4 app.

I am not sure what the indented use is for `[limit]` and how it relates to `pageSize` (which is emitted as part of the `(page)` event).

Seems like `pageSize` is something that depends on the height of each row and how many of those will fit into the available viewport of the table. Changing the `[limit]` doesn't seem to affect that.

What if I want to pull a certain number of rows from the server when it's time to pull more data? I am trying to create an infinite scroll with this strategy, but the docs are bit terse, so I am clear what all the moving parts.

Answer (score 1):

Looked into source code and found this. This is how pageSize generated.

> // if limit is passed, we are paging

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/components/datatable.component.ts

```
calcPageSize(val: any[] = this.rows): number {
    // Keep the page size constant even if the row has been expanded.
    // This is because an expanded row is still considered to be a child of
    // the original row.  Hence calculation would use rowHeight only.
    if (this.scrollbarV) {
      const size = Math.ceil(this.bodyHeight / this.rowHeight);
      return Math.max(size, 0);
    }

    // if limit is passed, we are paging
    if (this.limit !== undefined) return this.limit;

    // otherwise use row length
    if (val) return val.length;

    // other empty :(
    return 0;
}
```